# What is the simplest way to setup a basic logger in python?

Tags: python, logging

Ideally, setting up logging for simple scripts should take only one line of code. Unfortunately, most examples have up to ten lines of boilerplate. Is there a simpler way to get a basic logging setup?

Edit: ideally, I'd like timestamps, maybe log level, and not much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just made a basic logging configuration module:

```
import logging
from logging import info, warning, debug, error

logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s", level=logging.INFO)
```

That's not much, but now you can just:

```
import basic_logging as log
log.info("hello")
```

Which outputs useful information by default. This is as simple as it gets, but it uses a real logger, which means you can very simply switch to more complex logging in the future. I might even publish it to Pypi.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way to setup a logger is to use [the logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html).

Comment: Look at the basic examples: so much boilerplate. Then people wonder why people use print() instead.

Comment: I don't see what you call boilerplate in [this simple example](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/logging.html#a-simple-example)

Comment: I agree this one is not too bad. Unfortunately, I'd argue the defaults are not very well chosen. Having logger.info not print out anything by default is ... interesting. Also the default format string could be a bit nicer.

Answer (score -1):

There is a very nice module in Python called `logging`. You may find plenty of examples here [logging-cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html). Personally I use logging to log into a file and to be able to switch between different levels of verbosity when needed through whole of the project.

Comment: As stated, these have way to much boilerplate for such a simple thing as logging. I'm looking for something like basiclogging.getLogger(), ideally something I could store in my head.

Comment: Use print then, why bother?

Comment: Well for one I'd like to have timestamps. But it would also be nice to be able to move to more elaborate logging as the script matures.

Comment: Then an additional code that logging implies is not so high price